# Web3.js Smart Contract Method Call Returning Empty string

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development

I don't know why variable "totalItems" doesn't get incremented after my function call of "addItem" and thus mapping remains empty.

Smart Contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
    
    contract ToDoList{
        
    int8 nItems;
    int8 public totalItems;
    struct Item{
        int8 id;
        string name;
    }
    mapping(int8=>Item) public items;
    
    constructor() public {
        nItems=0;
        totalItems=0;
    }
        function addItem(string memory name) public {
            nItems++;
            totalItems++;
            items[nItems]=Item(nItems,name);
        }
        function removeItem(int8 id) public {
            if(id<=nItems){
            items[id]=Item(0,"");
            totalItems--;   
            }
            
        }
        function getItem(int8 id) public returns(string memory){
            return items[id].name;
        }
    }
```

Web3.js

```
var contractABI=[
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "int8"
        }
      ],
      "name": "items",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "id",
          "type": "int8"
        },
        {
          "name": "name",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function",
      "signature": "0x050fbc44"
    },
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "totalItems",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "int8"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function",
      "signature": "0x2799276d"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "constructor",
      "signature": "constructor"
    },
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "name",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "name": "addItem",
      "outputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "function",
      "signature": "0x27e9f294"
    },
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "id",
          "type": "int8"
        }
      ],
      "name": "removeItem",
      "outputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "function",
      "signature": "0x8b39ec51"
    },
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "id",
          "type": "int8"
        }
      ],
      "name": "getItem",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "function",
      "signature": "0x3e038994"
    }
  ];
  var contractAddress='0x92dA03e37Fdd0e783a966f1C589AD063E7148655';
  var web3=new Web3('http://localhost:9545');
  var todolist_sc=new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI,contractAddress);
  console.log(todolist_sc);
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

todolist_sc.methods.addItem("Smart Contract").call().then((result)=>{
  console.log("Called add Item")
todolist_sc.methods.totalItems().call().then((res)=>{
  console.log(res);
});
todolist_sc.methods.getItem(1).call().then((res2)=>{
  console.log(res2);
});

});


});
```

Web Console Output

```
Called add Item 
0 
<empty string>
```

I am new to solidity programming, I think the issue could be of solidity syntax.

Comment: To begin with, change `addItem("...").call()` to `addItem("...").send()`.

Comment: I am getting "VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas" error on Web console

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

What worked for me is that I wrote test cases for my smart contract methods and tested methods before migrating contracts.

Previously I did not wrote any test cases for smart contract methods.

I think its necessary now to test all methods and variables of smart contract before migration, otherwise they don't seem to work when invoked using web3.js in my case.